# How to add lines programmatically to an XML file section?

Tags: xml, c#-4.0

Here is the thing, let's say have this:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
</ItemGroup>
```

but I want to add another reference, how can I do that programmatically in C#?

I was trying with `StreamWriter` but I didn't figure it out how to do it.

Sorry I didn't clarify the programmatically detail.

Comment: Open the XML file in Notepad and type in the new line. If that doesn't answer your question, please [edit] it and be more specific about what you're asking. :-)

Comment: Open it in notepad, copy and paste a new reference line, then change the Include.  Or, you could [edit] to add a code tag or at least a description of what you're trying to do, because your question suspiciously lacks this information.

Comment: `XmlDocument` works really well. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx

Comment: Certainly if you search this site for `[c#] write XML`, you could find something that would get you started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a pretty easy to follow example:

```
        var filename = @"C:\temp\example.xml";

        // create new reference element
        var newReference = new XElement("Reference");

        // add to the include attribute
        newReference.SetAttributeValue("Include", "System.IO");

        // load file to doc
        var doc = XDocument.Load(filename);

        // get ItemGroup element
        var itemGroupElement = doc.Element("ItemGroup");

        // add the new reference
        itemGroupElement.Add(newReference);

        // save text
        File.WriteAllText(filename, doc.ToString());

        // save with declaration e.g. <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        doc.Save(filename);
```